# Using Swagger with ValidateAntiForgeryToken

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

I have the following code in my Account Controller

```
   [HttpPost]
   [AllowAnonymous]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]  // will stop Swagger from working
   public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IN 1");
    // etc
```

I am using Swashbuckle to generate the json for Swagger

If I try running the code from swagger without the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] tag then it works.

When I put the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] tag back then the Swagger call fails.

I expect that this is by design, however I wonder what the best practice is with this scenario.

I want the call in Swagger for documentation

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create separate controllers fro Swagger. Or you can just take out try it out button and leave just documentation.